# NodeJS child process race-condition between process.on(stdout) and process.on(exit)

Tags: node.js, typescript, selenium

I have an application that's (basically) has a parent and child process. The child process does several steps (in this case runs a test) and writes to STDOUT whenever a step of the test completes. This way, the parent process will always have the 'latest' results, so if the child exits pre-maturely for some reason the parent will know the last step completed.

**In child process**

```
console.log(doStep1());
console.log(doStep2());
console.log(doStep3());
process.exit();
```

**In the parent process**

```
c.stdout.on("data", () => storeLatestResultsInVariable())
c.on("exit", () => indicateTestExitedAndAlertUserToLatestResults());
```

The issue I'm noticing, is that the `onExit` callback is being triggered before the `storeLatestResultsInVariable()` callback is completed for the final `console.log`. So in some cases the user is alerted of the results of `doStep2` and not `doStep3`.

It's a little more complicated than that because the 'steps' are all asynchronous and `process.exit`is called in a function that runs if all 'steps' are completed or on an 'error', so I need to use `process.exit` to ensure the process completely closes out.

**My main question**: Is there any way for me to get Node to wait until the `storeLatestResultsInAVariable()` function completes before calling the `c.on("exit", ...)` code? Otherwise, is there a way to pass back data with `process.exit` so that I can use that data in my `c.on("exit", ...)` callback?

Really appreciate the help, hopefully the problem description was clear enough!

Comment: It's not supported for process.exit(). See https://github.com/Tapppi/async-exit-hook for reference.

Comment: What happens if you wait on the `close` event from the cild, instead of the `exit` event?